# Inconsistent file-scoped variable behavior in C++

Tags: c++

The title could be improved, but I'm not sure what the problem is. Suggestions are welcome. I have a custom enum class, `Color`:

```
// Color.h
class Color {
protected:
    int id;
    Color(int id) : id(id) {}
    void operator&(); //undefined
public:
    Color(const Color& r) : id(r.id) {}
    Color& operator=(const Color& r) {id=r.id; return *this;}
    bool operator==(const Color& r) const {return id==r.id;}
    bool operator!=(const Color& r) const {return id!=r.id;}
    operator int() const {return id;} //so you can still switch on it

    static Color Blue;          
    static Color Red;           
};

// Color.cpp
#include "Color.h"

Color Color::Blue(0);
Color Color::Red(1);
```

In `main`, I have a file-scoped array of `Colors`. When I print the values of the `Colors` in the file-scoped array, everything is correct:

```
// main.cpp
#include "Test.h"
using namespace std;

const Color mainColors[] = {Color::Red, Color::Red }; // values should be [1, 1]

int main()
{
    cout << "Main file-scoped colors: " << mainColors[0] << ", " << mainColors[1] << endl; // prints [1, 1]
    Test();
    return 0;
}
```

However, if I try to do the same thing in another file, `Test`, it does not work. When I print the file-scoped array, the values are incorrect, as if they are uninitialized.:

```
// Test.h
#include "Color.h"
void Test();

// Test.cpp
#include "Test.h"
const Color fooColors[] = {Color::Red, Color::Red}; // values should be [1, 1]

void Test()
{
    cout << "Test file-scoped colors: " << fooColors[0] << ", " << fooColors[1] << endl; // prints [0, 0]
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I assume it may have something to do with the enum members being static, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: There’s no such thing as “file scope” in C++.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Can you elaborate please? I've read about file scope in a number of places, including MSDN's article on scope in C++.

Comment: @Gareth: I would guess that some people might say "file scope" when the right term is "internal linkage"

Comment: @MooingDuck It works because I have an `int()` cast operator.

Comment: One way around this is to make Color::Blue and Color::Red into static functions which return instances of those colors.  Your (still static) arrays, mainColors and fooColors would then call those functions.  Since Blue & Red are no longer static instances, your problem goes away.

Comment: Another thing you can do is nix them as static member variables altogether and simply create const Color Blue(0) and const Color Red(1) instances in Color.h.  Any dependencies are now determined by header file inclusion order, not static initialization order.

Comment: @Andy, if you don't mind, I am going to add your suggestion to my answer.

Comment: @R Sahu - No problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is a result of unspecified order of initialization of static variables.

The behavior can easily change with slight changes to the build system (e.g debug vs non-debug, adding another file to the program, etc.)

Looks like `mainColors` in `main.cpp` get initialized after `Color::Red` and `Color::Blue` are initialized and `fooColors` in `Test.cpp` get initialized before `Color::Red` and `Color::Blue` are initialized.

**Work Around (Thanks to @Andy)**

Add `static` member functions `Blue()` and `Red()` to `Color`. Use them to initialize the variables in `main.cpp` and `Test.cpp`

In `Color.h`:

```
static Color Blue();
static Color Red();
```

In `Color.cpp`:

```
Color Color::Blue() {return Color(0);}
Color Color::Red() {return Color(1);}
```

In `main.cpp`:

```
const Color mainColors[] = {Color::Blue(), Color::Red() };
```

In `Test.cpp`:

```
const Color fooColors[] = {Color::Blue(), Color::Red()};
```

Answer (score 2):

It has everything to do with your enum members being static.  The order of initialization of static member data is undefined across translation units.  Essentially, you are getting lucky with the first call (main) and unlucky with the second call (Test.cpp).  There are several ways around this but this is the gest of it.

In this particular case, Test fooColors is getting initialized first using the *uninitialized* static data in your Color class.  This data then gets initialized second and then finally mainColors gets initialized from the now initialized values in Color::red and Color::blue.